# Compare value from input element in Perl

Tags: html, perl, comparison

I have a set of radio buttons that have the same name but different values.  I'm trying to get the value of the selected radio button and compare it to a preset value to see if they match.

```
<input type="radio" name="one" value="a">
<input type="radio" name="one" value="b">
<input type="radio" name="one" value="c">
```

Submitting this form...

**EDIT**

```
@answers = ("a", "a", "c");

for $key (param()) {
  $input {$key} = param($key);

  if ($key ne "firstName" and $key ne "lastName") {
    $value = "$_\n" for $input{$key};

    #The below values print out correctly.
    #a a
    #a a
    #c c
    print $value . " " . $answers[$i] . "<br/>";

    #When trying to compare them nothing happens.
    if ($value eq $answers[$i]) {
      print "TEST<br/>";
      $avg += 1;
    }
    $i++;
  }
}
```

So I need to push the value of the radio button into my array and then compare it to array answers.

Comment: FYI, the language is called [Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.12.3/perlfaq1.html#What's-the-difference-between-%22perl%22-and-%22Perl%22%3f), not PERL

Comment: I'll be more careful next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You always tack on a newline to $value, but none of the values in @answers have them.  So that's never going to match.

2) You assume you'll get the values in a particular order.  One day you'll get a different order, or one question will be omitted.  Then you'll be comparing e.g. question 1 to answer 2.

3) If you have multiple values for the same parameter (usually only an issue for checkboxes), you'll lose some values.  Your `"$_\n" for $input{$key};` implies that's a legitimate concern.  But your invocation of param() and your storage into a hash are in scalar context, which will always drop the other values.  You'll need to do use list context (for example `@values=param($key); $item{$key}=[@values]`) but this will require extra work elsewhere to check for each value whether it's a scalar or list reference.

Comment: Number 1 was the problem.  Thanks for pointing that out.  You also bring up a good point about point number 2.  I will be fixing this too.

Answer (score 0):

You can [ask for the values of a specific parameter](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CGI/lib/CGI.pm#FETCHING_THE_VALUE_OR_VALUES_OF_A_SINGLE_NAMED_PARAMETER%3a) so there's no need to store them in a separate hash.

```
my @values = param("one");
```

Then comparison is easy using a [smart match](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Smartmatch-Operator).

```
use v5.10;

if( @values ~~ @answers ) {
    ...they matched...
}
```

The final piece of the puzzle is to store your answers in a hash with the key being the parameter its for.

```
my %correct_answers = (
    one => ['a', 'a', 'c'],
    two => [1,2,3],
);
```

Then rather than looping over all parameters and extracting those which are NOT answer fields, because who knows what else the user will send in (yep, a user can feed your CGI program whatever fields they want in whatever order they want), you'd loop over the keys of `%correct_answers` to be sure you only look at the fields you expect.

```
for my $key (keys %correct_answers) {
    my $correct_answer = $correct_answers{$key};

    my @answer = param($key);

    if( @answer ~~ @$correct_answers ) {
        ...they matched...
    }
}
```

Comment: I forget that Perl has operators that PHP doesn't have.  Thanks for the help.